# Declaring and using a static array of constants

Tags: arrays, verilog, memory-address

I just got into verilog and I want to write a simple module that gets a 4 bit value in (called data) and outputs an 8bit value for a 7 segment display (called seven_seg).

```
module LCD_Encoder (
    input clk,
    input rst,
    input [3:0] data,       // digit to write 0-F
    output [6:0] seven_seg, // 7 segment out, LSB -> A, B, C, D, E, F, G <- MSB
    output dp               // decimal point
    );
```

I didn't want to write if statements all over checking for every 16 different values of the input data and then decide what to display, so I came up with an array like so:

```
// define 7 segment display, 16(different characters) * 7 bits(7 segment)
localparam [6:0] display [15:0] = {
    // GFE_DCBA
    7'b011_1111, // 0
    7'b000_0110, // 1
    7'b101_1011, // 2
    7'b100_1111, // 3
    7'b110_0110, // 4
    7'b110_1101, // 5
    7'b111_1101, // 6
    7'b000_0111, // 7
    7'b111_1111, // 8
    7'b110_1111, // 9
    7'b111_0111, // A
    7'b111_1100, // B
    7'b011_1001, // C
    7'b101_1110, // D
    7'b111_1001, // E
    7'b111_0001  // F
};
```

The decimal point on the 7segment display is handled seperately.
However I get this error:

> Constant value or constant expression must be used for initialization

Later I want to use the array like so:

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
    if (rst == 1'b1) begin
        seven_seg <= 7'b0;
    end
    else begin
        // use 4-bit (0-F) data as address for the array
        seven_seg <= display[data]; // does this work??
    end
end
```

however I fear that this will end in yet another failure.

I use ISE from Xilinx and for now and I simulate a spartan 6 xc6slx9 (my board arrives next month).

What am I doing wrong here?

Also since display is always going to be static, is there a way to only have it once and not create the circuit every time you instantiate a new module?

Comment: which line does the error point to?

Comment: @Serge `localparam [6:0] display [15:0] = {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need SystemVerilog support to have a localparam array. That requires Vivado, not ISE. To model this in Verilog, you need to pack the array into a single vector and take a slice out of the vector

```
localparam [0:(7*16)-1] display  = {
    // GFE_DCBA
    7'b011_1111, // 0
    7'b000_0110, // 1
    7'b101_1011, // 2
    7'b100_1111, // 3
    7'b110_0110, // 4
    7'b110_1101, // 5
    7'b111_1101, // 6
    7'b000_0111, // 7
    7'b111_1111, // 8
    7'b110_1111, // 9
    7'b111_0111, // A
    7'b111_1100, // B
    7'b011_1001, // C
    7'b101_1110, // D
    7'b111_1001, // E
    7'b111_0001  // F
};
seven_seg <= display[data*7+:7];
```

Also, your output ports need to be declared as `reg`

```
output reg [6:0] seven_seg,
```

Comment: doesn't the declaration need to be `localparam [(7*16)-1:0] display = {...`?

Comment: @FalcoGer, not if you want `display[data*7+:7]` to work

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in the syntax for declaration of localparam. To resolve this problem, you only need to add a `'` before `{` in your initial value like this:

```
localparam [6:0] display [15:0] = '{
// GFE_DCBA
7'b011_1111, // 0
7'b000_0110, // 1
7'b101_1011, // 2
7'b100_1111, // 3
7'b110_0110, // 4
7'b110_1101, // 5
7'b111_1101, // 6
7'b000_0111, // 7
7'b111_1111, // 8
7'b110_1111, // 9
7'b111_0111, // A
7'b111_1100, // B
7'b011_1001, // C
7'b101_1110, // D
7'b111_1001, // E
7'b111_0001  // F
};
```

Or you can use `initial` statement, by using this, your code is as follows:

```
// define 7 segment display, 16(different characters) * 8 bits(7 segment)
reg [6:0] display [15:0];
initial begin
    display[0] = 7'b011_1111; // 0
    display[1] = 7'b000_0110; // 1
    // Continue your display values in here
end
```

Comment: I have read that too about the ' before the array, however that gives me a different error.

Comment: also I didn't want to use registers because the values don't need to change and i feel that would be a waste of transistors and power.

Comment: You can do as Dave_59, he used the concatenation operator for value initialization.